# Integrate $\int\cos x\sin^{3} x \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $$\int{\cos x}{\sin^{3} x }dx$$

My attempt -

Let $u = (\sin x)^3 $

$\frac{du}{dx} = 3 \sin^{2}x \cos x $

$dx =\frac{1}{3 \sin^{2}x \cos x }du $

$\int{u}\frac{1}{3 \sin^{2} }du$

$\frac{(u)^2}{2} X \frac{1}{3\sin^{2}x} + C $

$\frac{\sin^{4}x}{6} + C $

However , my answer is wrong . I am suppose to get a $4$ in the denominator. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: ??? Set $u=\sin x$. Then $du=\cos x\,dx$ and your integral has the form $\int u^3\,du=\frac{u^4}{4}+C=\frac{\sin^4 x}{4}+C$.

Comment: You can't integrate $\frac{u}{3\sin^2(x)}$ in $u$ and treat $x$ like a constant. $x$ and $u$ are not independent.

Comment: Let $u=\sin x$ is more helpful...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I quite understand how you did it, but I'll take another look. In the meantime, here's how I would approach it:

$$\int \cos(x)\sin^3(x)\,dx $$

Let $u = \sin(x)$, then $du = \cos(x)\,dx$ and we can make the substitution $$\int \cos(x)\sin^3(x)\,dx = \int u^3\,du = \frac{u^4}{4}+c = \frac{\sin^4(x)}{4}+c$$

Edit: I think you went wrong in your choice of u. It's our goal to choose u such that du appears in the original statement (it's fine if du is off by a constant multiple). If we use $u=sin^3(x)$ then we'd want $3cos^2(x)$ to show up in the original integral, but $cos^2(x)$ doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

There's a neat little trick here so you don't have to use substitution at all: when you have a product of a simple function with a more complex function that involves its anti-derivative, there's a good chance you can just guess what the anti-derivative will look like using the "reverse" chain rule.

Here, $\cos x$ is the derivative of $\sin x$, so we have a pretty good guess that the chain rule is involved.  Since the more complex term with the sine is actually $\sin^3 x$, we can guess that the anti-derivative is close to $\left( \sin x\right)^4$.  Differentiating, we can see $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \sin x \right)^4 = 4\cos x \sin^3 x$$ so we were only off by a constant.  Thus the anti-derivative is $$\int {\cos x \sin^3 x dx} = \frac{1}{4}\left( \sin x \right)^4 + C$$

If you don't want to use the trick, you can do a formal substitution $u = \sin x$.